# Eliminating redundancy between different mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

My redux store has the following structure :

```
{ A: {item1, item2, item3},

 .....
  F : {item1, item2, item3},

  a : {anotherItem1, anotherItem2}

  .....
  z : {anotherItem1, anotherItem2}
}
```

That is to say, it is flat, and the properties have a normalized structure.
The problem is that I have about 8 different screens many of which will want to access a large number of specific items from these properties. This means that a lot of my `mapStateToProps` functions have redundant code.

For example suppose Screen1  defines `mapStateToProps` as follows

```
mapStateToProps(state){
 aitem1 : stata.a.item1,
 aFormatted : formatFunction(state.a.item2, state.a.item3)
 bitem1: state.b.item1,
 bFormatted : formatFunction(state.b.item2,  state.b.item2)
 ...
}
```

Now suppose Screen2 also wants to give its props the exact same state
as well as some other properties. Should then Screen2 have a mapStateToProps functions like this

```
mapStateToProps(state){
 aitem1 : stata.a.item1,
 aFormatted : formatFunction(state.a.item2, state.a.item3)
 bitem1: state.b.item1,
 bFormatted : formatFunction(state.b.item2,  state.b.item2)
 ...
 other stuff
}
```

The problem only worsens if Screens 3 and 4 also need that same stuff. So how can I avoid this problem?

Comment: The question isn't specific enough. *This means that a lot of my mapStateToProps functions have redundant code* - what are these functions exactly?

Comment: There are several ways to deal with that. One is to place the `mapStateToProps` somewhere and only import it where needed instead of repeating the code. Or you can go as far as writing a single component that connects to the store and use that as a provider component to wrap other components into.

Comment: @trixn I though about your first approach. The only problem would be that the imported mapStateToProps would need to return a giant object containing many items that the screen importing it doesnt need.

Comment: @estus I updated the question with an example

Comment: @DrawkcabEsrever Then it is not duplicated. Every connected component defines its own data reqirements through `mapStateToProps`. So it is no bad practice to have different `mapStateToProps` functions all over your application.

Comment: @DrawkcabEsrever So you want the common parts in `mapStateToProps` to be deduplicated?

Comment: This depends on what these functions have in common and where they are different. Proceed from there and write DRY functions. I believe this is not specific mapStateToProps. It's hard to suggest anything else without seeing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a separate function that selects a certain part of the state and call that in your `mapStateToProps` functions:

```
const getDataParts = state => ({
   foo: state.foo,
   bar: state.baz,
});
```

Then in `mapStateToProps` use it like:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    ...getDataParts(state),
    otherProp: state.someOtherProp,
});
```

**EDIT**:

Be aware that `mapStateToProps` may be called on **every** state change. If your selector does any calculations it will create new props for the component which will re-render even if the outcome of the calculation is the same. To prevent that you have to use memorized selectors like the library [`reselect`](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) provides.

For further explanations and examples see e.g. [Idiomatic Redux: Using Reselect Selectors for Encapsulation and Performance](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/12/idiomatic-redux-using-reselect-selectors/).

Comment: managed to find a post suggesting a similar approach. They call it using 'selectors' https://gist.github.com/abhiaiyer91/aaf6e325cf7fc5fd5ebc70192a1fa170

Comment: @DrawkcabEsrever You may find this library helpful: [`reselect`](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect). A problem with this kind of selectors can arise if they calculate fields and return a different object on every call. As `mapStateToProps` gets called on **every** state change this can have a significant performance penalty if you do not use memorized selectors because all connected components using this selector (any maybe their children) will re-render while nothing has really changed.

Comment: Yep. Please see my post [Idiomatic Redux: Using Reselect Selectors for Encapsulation and Performance](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/12/idiomatic-redux-using-reselect-selectors/) for explanations and examples.

Comment: excellent post mark. In my opinion your post did a better job introducing me to selectors then the official documentation